# Using $x^{1/2} = u$ as a substitution to show that one of the following is a definite integral

Tags: integration

Integrate with respect to $x$:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt x)}dx$$

or integrate with respect to $x$:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\cos(\sqrt x)}dx$$

The question asks to use the substitution $u = \sqrt x$ and show that just one of the following integrals is defined.

I got up to integrating both and getting

the integral of  $2/\sin(u)$ and $2/\cos(u)$ but since i got the same answers for both it seems to be wrong. Does anyone know where I've got wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @TPace There seems to be an error in the edit, please check. I don't think $\sin$ and $\cos$ should be under the square root.

Comment: You're correct but I don't know how to change it

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: yes thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sin\sqrt{x}}dx$$
If we let:
$$u=\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
and so:
$$dx=2\sqrt{x}du$$
and so we can say:
$$I=\int\frac{2u}{u\sin(u)}du=2\int\frac{1}{\sin(u)}du$$
which is a standard integral solved using:
$$I=2\int\csc(u)du=2\int\csc(u)\frac{\csc(u)+\cot(u)}{\csc(u)+\cot(u)}du$$
$$=-2\int\frac{-\csc^2(u)-\csc(u)\cot(u)}{\csc(u)+\cot(u)}du$$
now since the derivative of the bottom is the top, if we use:
$$v=\csc(u)+\cot(u)$$
we end up with:
$$I=-2\int\frac{1}{v}dv=-2\ln|v|+C=-2\ln|\csc(u)+\cot(u)|+C$$
we can now undo our $u$ substitution, giving:
$$I=-2\ln|\csc\sqrt{x}+\cot\sqrt{x}|+C$$
Now a similar process can be used to solve the integral involving $\cos$ but rather than multiplying by $\frac{\csc(u)+\cot(u)}{\csc(u)+\cot(u)}$ we can multiply by $\frac{\sec(u)+\tan(u)}{\sec(u)+\tan(u)}$. This means the answer will be equivalent but with $\csc$ replaced with $\sec$ and $\cot$ replaced with $\tan$. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt x)}\,dx=
2\int\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{x})}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\,dx=\\
2\int\frac{1}{\sin(\sqrt{x})}\,d\left(\sqrt{x}\right)=\ (u=\sqrt{x})\\
2\int\frac{1}{\sin u}\,du.
$$
Now, watch [**this YouTube video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe0l4G14h5w) on how to integrate $\int\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\,dx$ (it's a long process). It should be equal to $\ln\left|\tan{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right|+C$.

Comment: Why did you decide to use sin, like why not cos? When i attempted it cos was the one i thought was correct

Comment: Could you please tell me one more time what it is that you're trying to do? Because now I'm not sure if you understand the problem statement.

Comment: Note that it should be multiplied by $2$ rather than $1/2$

Comment: @HenryLee, my bad. I fixed it.